# USB mouse stops moving suddenly

Tags: usb, 16.04, mouse

Using ubuntu 14.04, suddenly my USB mouse stops working, even though it has power (the laser works).

When I try to shutdown, it takes a lot of time and finally I have to force shutdown by a long press on the power button. The mouse works again after a restart.

Any help please ...this is driving me crazy.

Comment: It is not completely clear from your question if the problem still exists (using past tense)?

Comment: sure it is still exists

Comment: Are all the packages on your system up-to-date? Have you installed all available updates?

Comment: always when i try to update i got update failed

Comment: i also read about solution that sometimes works for me which is rmmod usbhid and modprobe usbhid .but sometimes first command freeze